# Using Both onmouseover & onmouseout To Expand A Container

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm trying to use JavaScript and the HTML events "onmouseover" & "onmouseout" to expand and shrink a container. Basically when the mouse isn't hovering it is just a heading, but when the mouse is above the heading it expands and displays extra information.

Like example below, I am able to expand and display the extra text with added information on the bicycle.

```
    <div class="content" onmouseover="document.getElementById('Bicycle_Text').style.display='block'">
      <h1>The Bicycle</h1> 
      <p id="Bicycle_Text" style="display:none">Bicycles were first introduced in the 19th century in Europe.</p>
    </div>
```

However I would like the division to return to the original unexpanded state when the mouse moves off the division. I would do this using the "onmouseout" event and change the Javascript to display='None'. I'm unsure how to use both "onmouseover" & "onmouseout" events in the same line of text.

Is there any suggestions on how I do this or even a completely different way of doing it? I'm aware of the CSS hover function but can't figure out how it would expand like this one currently does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    function increase()
    {
        clearInterval(intervalid);
         intervalid=setInterval(zoomin,10);

    }
    function zoomin()
    {

        if(width<400){
            width=width+difference;
            document.getElementById("img1").style.width=width;
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(intervalid);
        }

    }
    function decrease()
    {
        clearInterval(intervalid);
        intervalid=setInterval(zoomout,10);
    }
    function zoomout()
    {

        if(width>300){
            width=width-difference;
            document.getElementById("img1").style.width=width;
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(intervalid);
        }

    }


<body>
    <img id=img1 onmouseover="increase()" onmouseout="decrease()" src=cah4.jpg  width="450">
```

Comment: This might help u